# declare myvar int(11); in mysql routine returns syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql, variables

I had a very long routine that used to work on a previous server.
I migrated it to a new server and I started having sql syntax error.

So I did a test:

```
create procedure test()
begin

declare myvar int(11);

select myvar;

end
```

By running this in mysql or in Mysql Workbench you should have a syntax error at 11) just before the ;

What's going on!

I've looked at mysql references on the subject they say `declare [variablename] [datatype]`

I've tried with other data types just to make sure I still get the same problem.

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare variables you don't give them display lengths. Those numbers are meant for table column definitions only.

Just do

```
DECLARE myvar INT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)
That won't work though. I've tried every over way.
With int only the syntax error moves to INT instead of ) (bracket)

Comment: @ndefontenay: It might have something to do with delimiters, I'm not sure. Try `DELIMITER //` before `CREATE`, and `DELIMITER ;` after `END`, and changing your inner `;` to `//`.

Comment: oh god! It worked! Except I didn't change the ; into // inside my code. It's really strange behavior. Do you have an explanation for that? Thanks a lot for the help. If I could vote it would have a thumbs up! Later then :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally declare would be first statement after begin. otherwise this will always give error.